# How to resolve the wcf endpint error while accessing WCF service from another machine

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

While accessing WCF service from another machine I got the following error

> There was no endpoint at http://localhost:14329/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by incorrect address or SOAP action

This is my service's **web.config** file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

This is my app.config file code from where i am hosting service

```
<system.serviceModel> <behaviors> <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="maxBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors> </behaviors> <services> <service behaviorConfiguration="maxBehavior" name="NILSevice.Service1">
<endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NILSevice.IService1"/> <host>
<baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
</baseAddresses></host> </service> </services> <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"> </serviceHostingEnvironment></system.serviceModel>
```

And here is my Client app.config file code

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:14329/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="NILServiceReference.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am new in WCF services programming. I want to access the service from one machine to another machine using LAN connection. I tried with above code but got the exception. Please help me out to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to remove the `localhost` from your client config - you're accessing the service on a different machine, so use the machine name instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks. i will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your client config file:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:14329/Service1.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="NILServiceReference.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

`localhost` tells the client to look for the service on the same machine the client is on.  Since you're trying to access the service on a different machine, this won't work.

Replace the `localhost` with the server name the service is on. For example, if the name of the machine is "MyBigBadServer", then it would be:

```
http://MyBigBadServer:14329/Service1.svc
```

Answer (score 0):

to your client side's enpoint address,
do you tried to use the hostname\computername\ipaddress of you server? instead of using of localhost? please see code below...hope this solve your problem

```
 <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://YOURSERVER||IP||HOSTNAME||COMPUTERNAME:14329/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="NILServiceReference.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: how to find YOURSERVER? IP? HOSTNAME?

Comment: do you already have an dedicated server to your WCF service? if you have one, connect it to your network and get its ipaddress. or open a command prompt as admin then type "ipconfig" to check its current ipv4  address..you will se something like this  

`Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe8:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:Xxx
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.xxx.xxx
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: to get your hostname, open command prompt just type "hostname" (without quotation mark)

it will return the value of your hostname

Comment: you enpoint address should look like this

`<endpoint address="http://192.168.xxx.xxx:14329/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="NILServiceReference.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />`


or using hostname


`
<endpoint address="http://ComputerNumber:14329/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="NILServiceReference.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />`

Comment: After doing this i got another error that **wcf there was an error downloading no connection could be made because the target machine  actively refused it**

Comment: hmm?does your FIREWALL "TURN ON" both server and client ?can you disable your firewal if its "TURN ON"? or just add port 14329 if possible.. then after that, try to use "telnet" to your server from the client while running your WCF service..do this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Telnet-in-Windows-7) to your server and using your client side try to open command prompt and type telnet hostname||ipaddress 14329. (ex telnet 192.168.xxx.xxx 14329 or telnet ServerComputerName 14329)

Comment: telnet is not starting

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have WCF endpoint issues I would recommend that you turn on WCF logging. This can be done server side, client side or both.

You do it by modifying the app.config file (or web.config file, depending on how you are hosting WCF) on each side accordingly.

Example, add this config section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
 <trace autoflush="true" />
 <sources>
   <source name="System.ServiceModel"
           switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
           propagateActivity="true">
     <listeners>
       <add name="sdt"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="MyWcfLogFile.svclog" />
     </listeners>
   </source>
 </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will produce a detailed XML file. To view the content a bit easier, install SvcTraceViewer from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is usually a huge time saver. Not only can you see all traffic and errors, you can also diagnose errors and see error messages otherwise not always easily available, for example details on serialization issues or warnings.